# install packages from docker-compose.yml into docker container

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, docker, nginx

I am a beginner with docker and docker-compose and i need your help.

I'm making PHP-NGINX-PostgresSQL symfony developement environment using docker-compose.

Here it is :

```
web:
    image: nginx:1.13.5
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./html:/html
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./html:/html
    links:
       - postgres
postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.5
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

Now, i would like to install php7.2-intl into my php container. So i would like to execute something like :

```
$ sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
```

Could you help me? I'm really stuck and also I dont have a Dockerfile file, just a docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Use a Dockerfile for your php image, then simply put `build: .`in place of `image`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get a PHP docker container with the intl extension, you need to extend the official PHP image.

To do so, declare the use of your own `Dockerfile` for your PHP image in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  php:
    # Remove this line
    # image: php:7-fpm

    # Add this one instead
    build: './docker/php'
    # ...
```

Then, add the following `Dockerfile` file to the `docker/php` folder:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        intl \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
        intl
```

You can now run `docker-compose build` to get your PHP container built with the Intl extension.

A few notes:

- I prefer to explicitly tell which PHP version I use (here "7.1.x") rather than the more generic "7.x" you defined with `php:7-fpm`.
- I preferred to use the `docker-php-ext-install` and `docker-php-ext-enable` command utilities provided by the PHP official image (see "How to install more PHP extensions" section in the [PHP image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, you really helped, especially on using dockerfile with docker-compose.