# Docker-compose WordPress with PHP extensions

Tags: php, wordpress, docker-compose

I have been using the following docker-compose.yml to build a WordPress environment. Everything has been working fine, except when I attempt to use PHP function `easter_date()` I receive an undefined function error.

Could anyone explain to me what I need to add to the YML file in order to include the PHP `easter_date()` extension?

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # This will import DB data from an sql file in your /data folder
      - ./data/migrate.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrate.sql # run sql commands in migrate.sql to update site urls in DB
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3400:3306" # mapping our ports for networking
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     environment:
       PMA_HOST: db
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       DOCKER_COMPOSE_YML_LOCATION: wordpress
     container_name: wp_phpmyadmin
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "3500:80" # mapping our ports for networking
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_MEMORY_LIMIT: 256MB
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes: # this is where we tell Docker what to pay attention to
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini # create custom uploads.ini which has an increased upload file size limit, memory etc.
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

I have attempted to include PHP extensions by inserting the following two lines:

```
  php: #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401966/install-packages-from-docker-compose-yml-into-docker-container
    build: './docker/php'
```

And then created a Dockerfile inside ./docker/php with

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

    RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-configure calendar
```

But I receive `ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile` when I run docker-compose build

Comment: `./docker/php` folder should be created from your docker-compose.yml file directory.

Comment: yes i added this folder and put Dockerfile inside it

Comment: strangely, i also see the same error when I remove the `php: build: './docker/php'` line from the yml file and run build again

Comment: How you run the build? do you run `docker-compose up`?

Comment: yes usually i do `docker-compose up`, but when I do `docker-compose build` i see an error

Comment: can you run `docker-compose down` first and builf afterwards? it should remove caches

Comment: ok it seems to be up now, but I still receive the php undefined function error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215148/discussion-between-hakob-hakobyan-and-user1444027).